# Cannot show data from PHP session

Tags: php

My point is after sending form show session data.

form.html:

```
 <form action="sendForm.php" name="f" method="post"  onsubmit="return sendForm()" >
    <div class="form">
        <label for="imie">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="nam" name="nam"/><br/>
        <label for="nazwisko">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"/><br/>
     </div>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send form"/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

sendForm.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nam'] = $_POST['nam'];
$_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];

header("Location: view-struct.php");
?>
```

view-struct.php:

```
<span class="label">Name</span><?php echo $_SESSION['nam']; ?><br/>
<span class="label">Surname</span><?php echo $_SESSION['surname']; ?><br/>
```

[EDIT] Question is closed, forgot to add  for session_start() in view-struct.php

Comment: did you add `session_start()` in view-struct.php file also ?

Comment: Any errors? the only thing missing from the code, to me seems to be what georoot said.   if that is not the problem, then consider turning on error reporting and let us know what error you get by updating your question

Comment: Thx georoot. I forgot to add <?php ?> in view-struct.php for session_start().